# Bigcommerce commenting out %%GLOBAL_productDetail%%

Tags: e-commerce, templating, bigcommerce, platform

For Bigcommerce, I am wondering how to comment out global variable that renders dynamic content onto the page.

I tried the following, but no cigar.

```
<!-- %%GLOBAL_productDetail%%-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigCommerce's template engine will ignore HTML comments like that, and mostly in part due to the fact they often use HTML comments themselves which have an affect on the one you're trying to invoke.

You will need to use jQuery to remove it from the DOM on load, or remove the tag entirely.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{{!-- commented out code --}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out that variable does not work because there are other comments in it (as @tbs_uk notes). When the first included comment is closed it will close your opening comment tag.

Remove the variable itself to remove the details section.